# Always do the event error $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post, http-post

I have a function for sending email.
This function works normally, but it always triggers the error function, any error did not occur (I'm receiving email).

**Follow my Javascript:**

```
//Send mail
$("div.contato-pedidooracao form").submit(function () {

    var dataString = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Contato/SendMail",
        data: dataString,
        dataType : "json",
        success: function (data) { alert("OK"); },
        error: function (data) { alert("Error"); }

    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendMail(string name, string phone, string cel, string email, string message)
{
    try
    {
        using (var mail = new MailMessage())
        {

            mail.To.Add("--mailhere--");

            mail.From = new MailAddress("\"" + name + "\" <" + email + ">" );
            mail.Subject = "Pedido de Oração - " + name;
            mail.Body = message;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = false;

            new SmtpClient().Send(mail);
        }
        return Json(new{Sucess = true, Message = "Email enviado com sucess!" } );

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new{Sucess = false, Message = ex.Message } );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to add `event.preventDefault` to stop the submit event from bubbling up and really submitting the form to the server.

```
$("div.contato-pedidooracao form").submit(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   ..... 
   .....
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try just adding return false to the submit function:

```
$("div.contato-pedidooracao form").submit(function () {

  var dataString = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "Contato/SendMail",
       data: dataString,
       dataType : "json",
       success: function (data) { alert("OK"); },
       error: function (data) { alert("Error"); }
   });
return false;  //right here
});
```

Comment: preventDefault is better - if there is a true error in the ajax call the form will still submit if using return false

Comment: @CResults: Got it. Understand. It has to do with the order of things. Thanks for pointing that out.